# image with href css animation (banner) not working (only in FireFox)

Tags: html, css, firefox, href, css-animations

I am using CSS keyframe and animation to make an auto-scroll banner (with `Keyframe` move out of `margin` e.g. `@keyframes teammove { 0% { margin-left: 0px; }  100% {  margin-left: -1200px; }`). Unfortunately it doesnt work on in firefox.

I tested with different size div and overflow setting, and eventually found it is the problem of the  `<a href = ""> </a>` tag.

Here are both working (without href) and non-working (with href) version of banner. Any solution would be helpful.

Working version: http://codepen.io/andy897221/pen/oLogXO

non-working version: http://codepen.io/andy897221/pen/XKzNYm

Comment: Second is not working also in Firefox developer edition !

Comment: @Vir yes that is the problem. The animation in firefox only works without a href. Any idea?

Comment: You can replace <a> tag with onclick event I post a demo below. So, you can use onclick event with image's and I hope problem may solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation would be better set on the wrapper, rather than each individual slide.

I've modified your pen. Removed the browser prefixes (they're rarely needed these days), moved the animation to the wrapper, and wrapped all the images in anchors. There's absolutely no need for JavaScript here;

```
.bannerframe {
  width: 3000px;
  height: 200px;
  animation: teammove 5s linear infinite;
}
```

Works in Chrome, Firefox and Edge

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grXgZJ

Comment: I eventually chose this as answer is because it is a more optimized solution. No javascript, lesser css and sitll achieve the same effect.

Comment: Remark: however this method will require you a precise calculation on the length of the banner, so it may not suit everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use javascript onclick event with image first and with image second calling function like,

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <body>

   <p>Click the button to set the href value to http://www.google.com.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Take me to google.com</button>

     <script>
       function myFunction() {
       location.href = "http://www.google.com";
      }
     </script>

    </body>
```

Use like,

```
    <img onclick="myFunction()" src="http://portfoliotheme.org/enigmatic/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2012/07/placeholder1.jpg" width="300" height="200" class="firstimg">
    <img onclick="myFunction()" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&bg=0099ff&txtclr=ffffff&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300&fm=png" width="300" height="200">
```